# static member within nested class in Java

Tags: java, class, static, inner-classes, class-members

I read java language specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).Here it says

1. An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or
   implicitly declared static.
2. Inner classes include local, anonymous and non-static member classes.
3. Inner classes may not declare static initializers or member
   interfaces, **or a compile-time error occurs**.
4. Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are
   constant variables, **or a compile-time error occurs.**

**But my question is 
why inner/nested class can not have static members & why a compile-time error occur?**
* I'm new in Java

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, inner/nested classes cannot have `static` members, because in order to access them you would need an instance of the nested class, which breaks the staticness.

Comment: That's not a really good justification... You need an enclosing instance to *create an instance of an inner class*. You don't need it to *refer to the class*. There was nothing forcing the Java designers to prevent static members of inner classes, it was purely a *choice*.

Comment: And the choice does make sense because there is no good point of placing the static members inside inner classes. The enclosing class is just as good a place for them.

Comment: Finally, there are such inner classes which do not require enclosing instances.